# Calculating Data in column continuosly from year to year

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I need your help
I need to calculate data in my column like this.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vXjy.png)

How can I calculate data in column initial balance?

In initial balance column, the data is being calculated by net_01 until net_04 calculated continuously from year to year.

currently, im working on oracle 12c. is there any function to achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question. Also, please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MERGE` statement with the `SUM` analytic function:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff97d/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( year, initial_balance, net_01, net_02, net_03, net_04 ) AS
SELECT 2013, 0, 100, 100, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2014, 0, -200, 100, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2015, 0, -300, 100, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2017, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID rid,
         SUM( net_01 + net_02 + net_03 + net_04 )
           OVER (
             ORDER BY year
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
           ) AS initial_balance
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    initial_balance = COALESCE( src.initial_balance, 0 )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff97d/5/0)**:
**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff97d/5/1)**:

```
| YEAR | INITIAL_BALANCE | NET_01 | NET_02 | NET_03 | NET_04 |
|------|-----------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| 2013 |               0 |    100 |    100 |    100 |    100 |
| 2014 |             400 |   -200 |    100 |    100 |    100 |
| 2015 |             500 |   -300 |    100 |    100 |    100 |
| 2016 |             500 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
| 2017 |             500 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
```